# Unity 2D - low fps in editor, 60+ fps in build

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, rigid-bodies

we are developing platformer game in Unity engine. Currently in our scene are 15 npc, movement is animation based, they are navigated via scripts, they can talk to player, fight etc. Rigid body does not handle collisions, it just detects ground as a trigger.  When build is created, all is nice and smooth 60fps, in editor it is 25 to 30, sometimes a lot lower which makes us sometimes a lot of problems. Do you have any experience how to make a game run smooth in editor? Thank you

Comment: Logging can drastically slow execution in the editor down. More than a few log messages per second will already be noticible.

Comment: We have only one Debug.Log for second.

Comment: Does hiding or closing the scene view help? Did you take a look at the profiler?

Comment: it helped a little

Answer (score 1):

Two top things are check that the profiler is not running and that the scene view is not open. These are the two most common causes (in my experience) of slow down in the editor.

You can also make sure there isn't any light baking going on, shouldn't be for 2D but worth checking.

Another thing to check is any editor only scripts, i.e. namespace UnityEditor.* usages (#if UNITY_EDITOR).

If you want an uncapped frame rate, go to project settings -> quality -> vsync mode, and turn off vsync.

Comment: +5 FPS, when stop recording profiler, light is okay and scene is close, but still 35 fps

Comment: Another thing to check is what, if any, editor only scripts are running. These are things using the UnityEditor.* namespace (or #if UNITY_EDITOR)

Comment: We have few scripts for stylizing inputs in editor inspector.What should we do? Thanks

Comment: Easiest thing to do is comment out the scripts and see if it helps, if it does improve fps, you can consider optimizing the scripts, but since build mode speed is good, it may not be worth it.

Comment: i removed my custom scripts for editor and still not result. How can i found other editor scripts installed with assets for example?

Comment: In visual studio, search for UnityEditor and see what files are using it. If nothing else is doing something custom, the slow-down must be elsewhere. You could also try re-enable the profiler and see what is taking the most time in the editor, might be interesting to see.

Comment: Only SpriteMeshInstance.cs. When i comment this code, many bugs are visible

Comment: What Unity version?

Comment: Well you've exhausted my ideas, good luck finding the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

if your editor is very slow you can go to the unity icon right click on it and select properties and in the target add -force-opengl in the end.

you can also increment the fps by

```
 void Start()
{
    //increase of fps
    Application.targetFrameRate = 300;
}
```

for more info go to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

try to logout to unity becuase sometimes the login can make the editor running slow

Comment: Still +- 35 FPS

Comment: hmm, i think your unity is bugged, try reintsall unity

Comment: have you fixed this?

Comment: No, We dont know solution

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to turn off Gsync(Vsync) on your monitor and graphics card control panel

Answer (score 1):

For me it was caused by GSYNC being enabled on windowed mode. I want GSYNC enabled on windowed mode because I play some games on windowed mode. To solve this problem I followed these steps for Unity.exe, which turns of GSYNC for Unity specifically:

Open the NVIDIA Control Panel
Go to the "Manage 3D Settings" Menu.
Select the "Program Settings" tab.
Select the game you want to turn off G-SYNC for, locate the "Monitor Technology" toggle, pick the "Fixed Refresh" option, and hit the "Apply" button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unity 2022.1.24f1, I get more fps in that build and also you can try using this free asset to get more fps.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/frame-rate-booster-120660